# Node.js Ubuntu Installation

Tags: git, ubuntu, node.js, terminal

I am following instructions from as someone suggested on stackoverflow:

> http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2284

After following all the steps when I command

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git && cd node
```

it shows

```
cloning..... 
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 100
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am using Ubuntu, terminals, etc. for the very first time. Can you please suggest what to do? Is there any problem with the configuration?

Thanks in advance for bearing such a question...

Comment: This works for me. a post with test case
http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Comment: I stuck on cloning to node.........using this link also.. :(

Comment: Do you need a http proxy server to access the web? You might need to set the `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables.

Comment: Try this: `git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git && cd node`

Comment: `nvm` is the way to go today: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are new to using node, I would suggest instead of bothering with git just download the source straight from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org).

Choose the 0.4.11 branch, its more stable.

From there, follow these directions:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev (may not be needed, but good idea anyways)
cd *your download dir*
tar xvf node-v0.4.11.tar.gz
cd node-v0.4.11
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If that still seems to cause problems, [this](http://apptob.org/) site allows you to quickly create an install script for node, your mileage may vary with it.

Answer (score 4):

As others stated above, what's included in the standard repo is quite old.

The following is a decent solution on Ubuntu 11 or higher:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on Ubuntu. Is there a reason not to install the package?

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: yes, node development is happening fast and the maintained packages are quite a bit behind, natty is at node version 0.2.6, node is at 0.4.11 (stable) and 0.5.5 (dev). Lots of api changes have happened between then and now.

Answer (score 0):

People who are getting the same Problem should try to download the zip file and then extract it and install. It solved my problem.

---

Comment: what if they want the git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step instruction on how to install node js in Ubuntu 10.04

http://blog.markmirandilla.com/2012/12/14/how-to-setup-node-js-in-ubuntu-10-04/